# iOS app crashes after deleting a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, deleted-comments

This crash is happening in version 1.3.1. I believe this bug was introduced in 1.3.0 or 1.3.1.

1. Delete a comment.
2. Select another comment.
3. Crash!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed in the beta channel and will be in the next App Store build. The crash occurs when the app tries to remove the toolbar from the now deleted row and the index is out of bounds. (Technically it tries animating the index path at `(n,NSNotFound)`.)

Comment: I miss the iOS app and the ultra fast bug fixes it got! ;)

Comment: @200_success Haven't listened to the podcast but that's the most recent release.  The new release is snaking its way through Apple's review process.

Comment: Confirmed fixed in version 1.3.2, released today.